# How to prevent a user from seeing all data in a collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, express

I'm writing an application that has seperate users.

Let's say I have two users with the role "doctor", these doctors each have a patient. Both the patients have personal data in a collection "data" and can only be viewed by the respective doctor.

So I have 2 collections:

- users: which contains 4 users. 2 With role 'doctor' and 2 with role 'patient'
- data: which contains personal data of the 2 patients and can only be accessed by the doctor of the patient.

How can I achieve this in mongodb without having to query every time the data-collection (with personal data of my patients) to check if it is a patient of my doctor.

I am using expressJs as webapi to talk with my mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending in the way your API is structured, a module like [node_acl](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl) could fit. Based on each user role (doctor/patient) you are able to restrict access to some resources.

I used this module in my app where a user can have role admin/user and it's pretty straigthforward, even for maintenance.

Regarding the part "only the respective doctor can access it's own patient data" you will have to use a route middleware to check if that doctor is elegible to access that patient's data (which will be a mongodb query).